# receive multiple div id from .parentsUntil()

Tags: javascript, jquery

Need to find `id` from multiple div what found by .parentsUntil() method (for a future draw and send ajax)

This is possible to use .parentsUntil for this.

Have script like this

```js
$(document).on('change', ':checkbox', (function(e) {
  var prod = $(this).closest("#product");
  var productUntilContainer = prod.parentsUntil('.container-fluid');
  console.log(productUntilContainer);
  /*
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
      prod.remove()
    } else {
      prod.remove()
    }*/
}));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid" id="product-list-container">

  <div id="progress" class="in-progress">In progress

    <div id="18-11-20" class="datess">18-11-20

      <div id="Marja">
        <h4>
          <p class="badge badge-secondary">
            Marja
          </p>
        </h4>

        <div id="product" class="col-lg-3 no-gutter">

          <div class="e-co-product no-gutter row">
            <a class="product-image" align="center" href="">
              <img class="img-fluid" src="
                                                                            http://localhost/blog/public/product_img/7.jpg
                                                                                                                " data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalGallery" alt="">
            </a>
            <div class="product-info col no-gutter ">
              <a href="" class=" align-self-center">
                <h6 align="center">Product №7 en</h6>
              </a>
              <div class="coninfo row justify-content-between no-gutter">
                <div class="params">
                  пар #4 en : 3043
                  <br> пар #3 en : 9740
                  <br> пар #3 en : 8907
                  <br>
                </div>
                <div class="price text-right">
                  <p class="product-price"><span class="ml-2"><del>$1172.00</del></span>
                  </p>
                  <p class="product-price">$2211.00</p>
                  <p class="manufacturer">Manufacturer #1</p>
                </div>
                <!--end price-->

              </div>
              <!--end coninfo-->
              <div class="btn-shop row justify-content-between no-gutter">
                <div class="shopsicons ">
                  <img src="http://localhost/blog/public/shops/3.png " alt="" class="shop-img">
                </div>
                <div class="custom-control form-control-lg custom-checkbox">
                  <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="112">
                  <label class="custom-control-label" for="112"></label>
                </div>

              </div>

            </div>
            <!--end product-info-->
          </div>
          <!--e-co-product-->
          <hr class="divider">
        </div>
        <!--product-->
      </div>
      <!--site div-->
    </div>
    <div id="19-11-20" class="datess">19-11-20
      <div id="Marja">
        <h4>
          <p class="badge badge-secondary">
            Marja
          </p>
        </h4>
        <div id="product" class="col-lg-3 no-gutter">
          <div class="e-co-product no-gutter row">
            <a class="product-image" align="center" href="">
              <img class="img-fluid" src="
                                                                            http://localhost/blog/public/product_img/9.jpg
                                                                                                                " data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalGallery" alt="">
            </a>
            <div class="product-info col no-gutter ">
              <a href="" class=" align-self-center">
                <h6 align="center">Product №9 en</h6>
              </a>
              <div class="coninfo row justify-content-between no-gutter">
                <div class="params">
                  пар #3 en : 2853
                  <br> пар #1 e : 6405
                  <br> пар #3 en : 2564
                  <br> пар #1 e : 8738
                  <br>
                </div>
                <div class="price text-right">
                  <p class="product-price"><span class="ml-2"><del>$1660.00</del></span>
                  </p>
                  <p class="product-price">$2653.00</p>
                  <p class="manufacturer">Manufacture #5</p>
                </div>
                <!--end price-->

              </div>
              <!--end coninfo-->
              <div class="btn-shop row justify-content-between no-gutter">
                <div class="shopsicons ">
                  <img src="http://localhost/blog/public/shops/3.png " alt="" class="shop-img">
                </div>
                <div class="custom-control form-control-lg custom-checkbox">
                  <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="114">
                  <label class="custom-control-label" for="114"></label>
                </div>

              </div>

            </div>
            <!--end product-info-->
          </div>
          <!--e-co-product-->
          <hr class="divider">
        </div>
        <!--product-->
      </div>
      <!--site div-->
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="complete" class="complete">Complete
    <div id="18-11-20" class="datess">18-11-20
      <div id="Marja">
        <h4>
          <p class="badge badge-secondary">
            Marja
          </p>
        </h4>
        <div id="product" class="col-lg-3 no-gutter">
          <div class="e-co-product no-gutter row">
            <a class="product-image" align="center" href="">
              <img class="img-fluid" src="
                                                                            http://localhost/blog/public/product_img/9.jpg
                                                                                                                " data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalGallery" alt="">
            </a>
            <div class="product-info col no-gutter ">
              <a href="" class=" align-self-center">
                <h6 align="center">Product №9 en</h6>
              </a>
              <div class="coninfo row justify-content-between no-gutter">
                <div class="params">
                  пар #3 en : 2853
                  <br> пар #1 e : 6405
                  <br> пар #3 en : 2564
                  <br> пар #1 e : 8738
                  <br>
                </div>
                <div class="price text-right">
                  <p class="product-price"><span class="ml-2"><del>$1660.00</del></span>
                  </p>
                  <p class="product-price">$2653.00</p>
                  <p class="manufacturer">Manufacture #5</p>
                </div>
                <!--end price-->
              </div>
              <!--end coninfo-->
              <div class="btn-shop row justify-content-between no-gutter">
                <div class="shopsicons ">
                  <img src="http://localhost/blog/public/shops/3.png " alt="" class="shop-img">
                </div>
                <div class="custom-control form-control-lg custom-checkbox">
                  <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="111" checked="">
                  <label class="custom-control-label" for="111"></label>
                </div>

              </div>

            </div>
            <!--end product-info-->
          </div>
          <!--e-co-product-->
          <hr class="divider">
        </div>
        <!--product-->


      </div>
      <!--site div-->
    </div>
    <div id="19-11-20" class="datess">19-11-20
      <div id="Marja">
        <h4>
          <p class="badge badge-secondary">
            Marja
          </p>
        </h4>
        <div id="product" class="col-lg-3 no-gutter">
          <div class="e-co-product no-gutter row">
            <a class="product-image" align="center" href="">
              <img class="img-fluid" src="
                                                                            http://localhost/blog/public/product_img/no_img.jpg
                                                                                                                " data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalGallery" alt="">
            </a>
            <div class="product-info col no-gutter ">
              <a href="" class=" align-self-center">
                <h6 align="center">Pr223 №2 en</h6>
              </a>
              <div class="coninfo row justify-content-between no-gutter">
                <div class="params">
                  пар #1 e : Beetle
                  <br>
                </div>
                <div class="price text-right">
                  <p class="product-price"><span class="ml-2"><del>$421.00</del></span>
                  </p>
                  <p class="product-price">$115.00</p>
                  <p class="manufacturer">Manufacturer #3</p>
                </div>
                <!--end price-->

              </div>
              <!--end coninfo-->
              <div class="btn-shop row justify-content-between no-gutter">
                <div class="shopsicons ">
                  <img src="http://localhost/blog/public/shops/3.png " alt="" class="shop-img">
                </div>
                <div class="custom-control form-control-lg custom-checkbox">
                  <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="113" checked="">
                  <label class="custom-control-label" for="113"></label>
                </div>

              </div>

            </div>
            <!--end product-info-->
          </div>
          <!--e-co-product-->
          <hr class="divider">
        </div>
        <!--product-->
      </div>
      <!--site div-->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: so what's the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not exactly easy to tell what it is you want to happen, or what problem you're having, but if you want to get a list of ids from your `.productsUntil` list, take this as an example:

```js
$('button').on('click', function() {
    console.log('hello world');
    var prod = $(this).closest("#product");
  var productUntilContainer = prod.parentsUntil('.container');
  console.log(productUntilContainer.length);
  
  const ids = [];
  productUntilContainer.each(function() {
    ids.push($(this).attr('id'));
  });
  
  console.log(ids);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="container">
  <div id="one">
    <div id="two">
      <div id="three">
        <div id="product">
          <button>click</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I want! I just tried using productUntilContainer[1] but this unable to use `.attr() method`